# Python regex - Replace all but a few words

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

Imagine you have the following String:

```
"badger randomword badger mushroom mushroom somethingelse"
```

I want to keep the words "badger" and "mushroom", and replace every other word with "mushroom":

```
"badger mushroom badger mushroom mushroom mushroom"
```

But I can't find a regex to match "everything except the words badger and mushroom". Can you help me?

Comment: Check for bader or mushroom, negate it?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/aV4rE9/1

Comment: I would be able to post a non-regex answer, would that be fine too? Regex are sometimes overpowered!

Comment: Non regex way is:      " ".join([x if x == 'badger' else 'mushroom' for x in "badger randomword badger mushroom mushroom somethingelse".split()])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work

```
(?!\bbadger\b|\bmushroom\b)\b[^\s]+\b
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aV4rE9/1)**

*Python Code*

```
p = re.compile(r'(?!\bbadger\b|\bmushroom\b)\b[^\s]+\b')
test_str = "badger randomword badger mushroom mushroom somethingelse"
subst = "mushroom"
result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/u1AIeT)**

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida you can use the site https://regex101.com/ 
it has some brief explanation of what is going on in the regex

Answer (score 2):

A simple non-regex oneliner to perform this task would be -

```
new_string = ' '.join(word if word == 'badger' else 'mushroom' for word in original_string.split())
```

I would advise against using a complex regular expression here since [Beautiful Is Better Than Ugly](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) with function parameter which would make the pattern really simple:

```
import re

s = "badger randomword badger mushroom mushroom somethingelse"
re.sub('\w+', lambda x: 'badger' if x.group(0) == 'badger' else 'mushroom', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-regex solution (and much easier to read) would be this:

```
oldstring = "badger randomword badger mushroom mushroom somethingelse"
newstring = ""

for part in oldstring.split(" "):
    if part in ["badger", "mushroom"]:
        newstring += part
    else:
        newstring += "mushroom"
    newstring += " "

newstring = newstring[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(?!badger\b)\b\w+\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uM7dE5/1)

**Explanation:**
`(?!…)`: Negative lookahead [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bI9fA5/1)
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)
`\w`: "word character": ASCII letter, digit or underscore [sample](https://regex101.com/r/uQ2lG4/1)
`+`: One or more [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wV7cV2/1)

Python

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?!badger\b)\b\w+\b')
test_str = u"badger randomword badger mushroom mushroom somethingelse"
subst = u"mushroom"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)#badger mushroom badger mushroom mushroom mushroom
```