# Replace all hyphens except in between two digits

Tags: python, regex

Following the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862693/python-regex-replace-all-but-a-few-words) I'm trying to replace a hyphen if it does not appear in a US postal code.

The logic is:

- Dont match hyphen in between digits
- Match hyphen

I've tried to acheive this using:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?!\d+\-\d+)-') # regex here
test_str = "12345-4567 hello-you"
re.sub(p, " ", test_str)
```

- Expected output: `12345-4567 hello you`
- Actual Output: `12345 4567 hello you`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?!(?<=\d)-\d)-')
test_str = "12345-4567 hello-you 45-year N-45"
print(re.sub(p, " ", test_str))
# => 12345-4567 hello you 45 year N 45
```

See the [Python demo](https://rextester.com/PTL81615) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G96IEl/1).

The `(?!(?<=\d)-\d)-` regex matches a

- `(?!(?<=\d)-\d)` - a location in a string that is not immediately followed with a `-` (that is immediately preceded with a digit) followed with a digit
- `-` - a hyphen.

Another approach is to match and capture postal code like strings to keep them and replace `-` in all other contexts:

```
re.sub(r'\b(\d{5}-\d{4})\b|-', r'\1 ', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G96IEl/3) and the [Python demo](https://rextester.com/EYA41070).

Note `\b(\d{5}-\d{4})\b` matches and captures into Group 1 a word boundary position first, then matches any five digits, a hyphen, four digits and again a word boundary. The `\1` backreference in the replacement pattern refers to the value captured in Group 1.